# Which language support i need to choose before build? (Publish WP app)

Tags: windows-phone, windows-store-apps, windows-store

So here is the picture:
[Sotre Listings (Languages support in package)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfRCO.png)

Why there are two Hungarian? I need to fill in everything twice! (like description, pictures etc...)
What i need to do? Or its normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the second one **Hungarian (Hungary)** is targeting on Hungarian market while the first one single **Hungarian** is for other country/region where people also speak Hungarian, like Romania. There are around 14 million people speaking Hungarian language. About 10 million of them live in Hungary and the rest 4 million spread over Romania, Czechoslovakia and Yugoslavia etc.

The counterpart, you might see in Store listing languages, is about **Italian**, **Italian(Italy)** and **Italian(Switzerland).** The second one targets on Italian market and the third one for Swiss market while the first **Italian** targets on the rest country/region where people mainly speak Italian.

Now you could complete the Store listing page by selecting language you want to support. More details, please refer to **[Store listing languages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/publish/create-app-store-listings)**.